# Write img src to div

Tags: javascript

This is the original code:

```
var milli = new Date().getMilliseconds(),
url = "/var/mobile/Documents/Artwork.jpg?" + milli;
albumart.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + url + "')";
```

I want to write something like this in the `albumart` div.

This is what I tried:

```
var milli = new Date().getMilliseconds();
albumart.innerHTML = '<img src="/var/mobile/Documents/Artwork.jpg?' + milli + ">';
```

What would be the correct format for this?

Comment: you're missing an opening `'` in the last part of the string (should be `'">'`)

Comment: it depends on what you want to do!! plz clarify your question

Comment: Other than the quote typo, this looks fine. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Is that typo in the real code, or a copying error?

Answer (score 0):

maybe [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) can help you:

```
var test = document.createElement('div');
var milli = new Date().getMilliseconds();
test.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', '<img src="/var/mobile/Documents/Artwork.jpg?' + milli + '">')
```

Comment: Nothing in the question suggests he needs to keep the old contents of the DIV.